# SSHCommandClientEndpoint, twisted. How to execute more than one commands?

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, endpoint

I need to execute a few ssh commands. I have found some example but it is for one command, for example 'pwd':

```
endpoint = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.newConnection(reactor, 'pwd',
                                            username, host, port,
                                            password=password,
                                            agentEndpoint=agent
                                        )
factory = MonitoringFactory()
d = endpoint.connect(factory)
d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.finished)
```

What should i do to execute 2 commands, for example 'pwd', 'ls'. Should i make 2 endpoints? Will it be right? But it will make 2 ssh connections, isn't it? It seems to me there should be another way to do what i want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection` to run multiple commands over a single SSH connection.

```
from twisted.conch.endpoints import SSHCommandClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet.endpoints import connectProtocol

# Open a connection with a long-running command so that the connection
# is re-usable for other commands indefinitely.
command = b"cat"

endpoint = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.newConnection(
    reactor, command, username, host, port,
    password=password, agentEndpoint=agent)

connecting = connectProtocol(endpoint, Protocol())
def connected(protocol):
    conn = protocol.transport.conn
    a = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection(conn, b"pwd")
    b = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection(conn, b"...")
    c = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection(conn, b"...")
    ...
connecting.addCallback(connected)
...
```

Keep in mind that these commands still don't run in the same shell session though.  So you may not necessarily find commands like `pwd` terrible useful.

If you want to run multiple commands in a single shell session then you need to use shell to combine the commands:

```
# Open a connection with a long-running command so that the connection
# is re-usable for other commands indefinitely.
command = b"pwd; ls foo; cd /tmp"

endpoint = SSHCommandClientEndpoint.newConnection(
    reactor, command, username, host, port,
    password=password, agentEndpoint=agent)

...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is something in the first example that is elided that I am missing, but when I try to use the `SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection()` method, nothing seemed to happen.  Since it returns an endpoint, I tried calling `connect()` on it to create a second protocol instance, but when I try to do that, I get an exception:  `exceptions.AttributeError: _CommandChannel instance has no attribute 'openChannel'` in tx.conch.endpoints.py line 666, Twisted v16.1.0

Comment: I think I figured out my confusion-- in your example, the `SSHCommandClientEndpoint.existingConnection()` calls are using `proto.transport` as the `connection` argument, but this is not correct.  You need to use `proto.transport.conn`.  This could be made more clear in the documentation, as this isn't obvious, and I needed to dive into the source code and do a fair amount of code introspection before I realized what was required.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for that mistake.  I agree with you that these aren't the easiest APIs to use.  There's a lot of complexity in SSH and Conch doesn't manage to keep it all well abstracted.